# Backup a file while custom feature activated?

Tags: development, feature-activation, feature-receiver

We have a custom application page "custom.aspx" on the Layout folder, would like to rename the original file "custom.aspx" to "custom_bak.aspx" before the updated/modified custom application page "custom.aspx" is placed on the same location while activating a custom feature.

any clue? how would I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `FeatureReceiver` that is triggered when a Feature is activated as described at http://salaudeen.blogspot.com/2011/03/sharepoint-feature-for-file-system.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are providing "custom.aspx" through your custom solution/feature the most logical place for doing backup of that file is by using [SPFeatureReceiver.FeatureDeactivating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.featuredeactivating.aspx) method. So when you deactivate your feature backup is created and when you again activate it the new file will be provisioned.

If you are using [modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462994.aspx) or if you are providing application pages your file is most likely already deployed once [SPFeatureReceiver.FeatureActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.featureactivated.aspx) fires so this is not good place to put backup code. Only scenario where this can be done is if you are doing all your file provisioning in code.